AWS lambda snapstart. Timeout breaks snapstart runtime environment
I have a problem with snapstart on AWS lambda. It seems that timeout breaks snapstart feature. At the next invocation after timeout the objects initialized during beforeCheckpoint are nulls. Im using java 21. I have prepared a sample project that allows to reproduce this issue: https://github.com/dfgrzyska/lambda-timeout-snapstart
public class SimpleHandler implements Resource, RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, String> {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    private SimpleService simpleService;

    public SimpleHandler() {
        Core.getGlobalContext().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "is simple service null? " + (simpleService == null));
        var type = input.get("httpMethod");
        if (type.equals("GET")) {
            simpleService.handleGet();
        } else {
            simpleService.handlePost();
        }
        return "OK";
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeCheckpoint(org.crac.Context<? extends Resource> context)
            throws Exception {
        simpleService = new SimpleService();
        System.out.println("Before checkpoint");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterRestore(org.crac.Context<? extends Resource> context)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After restore");
    }
}

public class SimpleService {
    public void handleGet(){

    }

    public void handlePost(){
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

What im doing:

Uploading mentioned project to aws lambda with enabled snapstart feature

Lambda has set 8s timeout

Publish new version

Using aws console i run lambda with the following Event JSON:
{
  "httpMethod": "GET"
}


Using aws console i run lambda with the following Event JSON:
{
  "httpMethod": "POST"
}


Using aws console i run lambda with the following Event JSON:
{
  "httpMethod": "GET"
}



What im expecting:

Third request returning "OK"

What resulted:

First request returns "OK"

Second request ends with timeout(as expected)

Third requests ends with the following exception: "errorMessage": "Cannot invoke \"test.lambda.timeout.application.SimpleService.handleGet()\" because \"this.simpleService\" is null",


I know that during lambda timeout a runtime env is recreated. It seems that during this recreation snapstart restore is not being used. Is this normal? Am I missing something?

Any resolution on this? You are right about:

during lambda timeout a runtime env is recreated. It seems that during this recreation snapstart restore is not being used.

The logs after timeout show INIT_REPORT meaning lambda is not starting at runtime RESTORE_START for SnapStart (this is a separate example than you have provided):


(Beginning of Lambda Instance)
RESTORE_START Runtime Version: java:17.v31 
RESTORE_REPORT Restore Duration: 570.57 ms
...
...
...
758c48fc-b437-45d1-83af-3cc121a334c0 Task timed out after 15.02 seconds
END RequestId: 758c48fc-b437-45d1-83af-3cc121a334c0
REPORT RequestId: 758c48fc-b437-45d1-83af-3cc121a334c0 Duration: 15017.49 ms Billed Duration: 15000 ms Memory Size: 2048 MB Max Memory Used: 197 MB
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 552.89 ms
...
...
...
(Any objects initialized in beforeCheckpoint() throw NullPointerException)



This may be expected behavior with SnapStart, but there is not much documentation on this issue. While I do not have an exact solution for you, there are ways to restore the instance because this Lambda will keep throwing NullPointerException's until it goes cold again. Once a new lambda instance is initialized, this is fixed because the Lambda initializes in the RESTORE_START on cold start.
AWS doesn't offer a solution out of the box. I have found the easiest way to do this with SnapStart enabled is creating a new Version of the Lambda in the management console, switching your SnapStart alias to this version, then switching back to the originally deployed version.
There are other ways to accomplish this in this thread.
